# Sharepoint 2010 Project package: Cannot add a new project output assembly to the package

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2010, assemblies, sharepoint-2010, packaging

When creating a Sharepoint 2010 project in VB.NET and wanting to deploy an additional referenced assembly you cannot add a new project output assembly to the package.

To replicate the issue:

1. Open Sharepoint 2010 project in Visual Studio 2010
2. Open "package\package.Package"
3. Select "Advanced"
4. In the Additional Assemblies area select "Add | Add assembly from Project Output..."

This error is then presented:

```
Cannot add a new project output assembly to the package.

The path is not of a legal form.
```

**Any ideas on what the "path" is that is not "of a legal form"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but sounds like you are hitting same bug as as [Andrew Connell](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2009/11/19/fyi-ndash-interesting-little-bug-in-vs-2010-beta-2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Remove any Solution Folders from your solution and you should be able to access the Add assembly from Project Output dialog.

This has been acknowledged by MS as a bug in the current Visual Studio 2010 Beta:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/2201baa0-70a0-424e-931a-f20c7c4091d6